# Measuring distance between two points

Tags: image-processing, scikit-image

I want to measure the distance between two points using **scikit-image**. Here is the image:
[image]

In the above photo I want to measure the distance between the **red point** and **black point**. The unit of measurement does not matter to me as I want to normalize the distance by the end of the day. Any idea how I can do it? 
Thanks

Comment: Whats wrong with euclidian distance?

Comment: What is the difficulty? It would be good if you could explain in your question where you got stuck attempting to solve this. Can you find the coordinates of the two points? Do you know how to compute the distance between two coordinates?

Comment: It might be a simple question. I asked it because I am not familiar with the scikit-image. I need to know how I can implement it in scikit-image. In other words I need an example code to find the coordinate of the points (as shown in the above image) and find the distance between them. However if the coordinates are found, the distance is obviously known.

Comment: Is there anybody here to help me with that?!

Comment: So your original question now turns into object detection. This will be very broad unless you describe more. Will all the images have same dimensions? Will all the images you work on have only two objects?  Will they always be circle? Will they always be red and black? You can start here:- [Example1](http://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/edges/plot_contours.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-edges-plot-contours-py), [Example2](http://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/features_detection/plot_corner.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-features-detection-plot-corner-py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the job done through the following stepwise procedure:

- Compute distance from each pixel to red and black colors.
- Binarize using an appropriate `threshold`.
- Perform morphological closing.
- Determine the centroid coordinates of the resulting blobs.
- Calculate the distance between centroids.

Hopefully the code below will put you on the right track:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import io
from skimage.morphology import closing
from skimage.measure import regionprops
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import ConnectionPatch

img = io.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbOmy.jpg')

red = [255, 0, 0]
black = [0, 0, 0]

threshold = 10

dist_from_red = np.linalg.norm(img - red, axis=-1)
dist_from_black = np.linalg.norm(img - black, axis=-1)

red_blob = closing(dist_from_red < threshold)
black_blob = closing(dist_from_black < threshold)

labels = np.zeros(shape=img.shape[:2], dtype=np.ubyte)
labels[black_blob] = 1
labels[red_blob] = 2

blobs = regionprops(labels)

center_0 = np.asarray(blobs[0].centroid[::-1])
center_1 = np.asarray(blobs[1].centroid[::-1])

dist = np.linalg.norm(center_0 - center_1)
```

#### Demo

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.imshow(img)

con = ConnectionPatch(xyA=center_0, xyB=center_1, 
                      coordsA='data', arrowstyle="-|>", ec='yellow')
ax.add_artist(con)

plt.annotate('Distance = {:.2f}'.format(dist), 
             xy=(center_0 + center_1)/2, xycoords='data',
             xytext=(0.5, 0.7), textcoords='figure fraction', color='blue', 
             arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", color='blue'))
plt.show(fig)
```

[image: Annotated image]

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It was really helpful. However I am getting this error when running your solution:  red_blob = closing(dist_from_red < threshold)
TypeError: closing() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: What is the second argument that we need to include in "closing()" to get it to work?

Comment: What versions of Python and scikit-image are you using?

Comment: I just installed the latest version of scikit-image on python 3.5. New error comes up:   ImportError: No module named 'scipy._lib.decorator'